# Does incrementing a copied pointer increment the original also?

Tags: c, pointers

In C, if you have something like this:

```
int obj = 5;
int * ptr = &obj;
int * ptr2 = ptr;
ptr2++;
```

Is ptr incremented as well, or just ptr2? I guess what I'm getting at is if assigning a second pointer from a main one to then do function operations is a good way to do this without messing up the position of the first pointer. This is for a project where I'm editing several functions. I have access to a pointer to the object but not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

The first pointer (`ptr`) will be unaffected because you are setting the second ptr (`ptr2`) to have the VALUE (`&obj`) of the first (`ptr`), just like if you had the below code:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a;
b++;
```

Only `b` will increment, not `a`

Comment: Does the same hold true if the object being pointed to is an array? Will that second pointer know to move to the second array element?

Comment: @Coder4Lyfe Yes, so long as the pointer is the correct type. Doing arithmetic on pointers is different than on other types, as the pointer will change in units of the size of the type they point to. So, in your example, the operation `ptr2++` will result in the value of `ptr2` incrementing by 4 (assuming 4byte ints). If it was a `char*`, it will increment by 1 as `char` is 1byte in size. For more on this, see first result on Google (Search: "Pointer Arithmetic in C"):
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Answer (score 1):

If you copy a sheet of paper and burn the copy, is the original then lost forever?

Of course not!

---

- The above does not change if we talk about a pointer or other object in C.
- While creating a pointer to one past an object is ok, that's probably not what you want to do there.
- And naturally, copying the pointer to an object has no effect on the object, it is not copied.
- Also, it does not matter which pointer to some object you take, they will all see it the same way (if they have the same type, naturally).

Comment: This is the third time today someone downvoted one of my answer shortly after I got the first upvote (of all answers on the same question). Is it an epidemic??

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the value of `ptr2` only.  `ptr` still holds the address to `obj`.